# Found a fake white space(a character similar to white space) in php code

Tags: php, html, utf-8, binary, utf-16

I got hundreds of errors in a PHP code which i just copied from a website. But i don't see any problems in that code(100% sure).
Now i noticed that,this errors are because white spaces in that codes are not real white spaces(they are just looking similar to white spaces).

Please let me know what character it is.?

- Binary code of that character is: `1100001010100000`
- Hex of that character is : `a0`

Comment: Binary... Don't you have hex? And in what encoding? UTF-8? Unicode defines a lot of additional whitespace codepoints.

Comment: \xC2 \xA0 - UTF-8 NONE-BREAKING SPACE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a replacement of that character with a regular space?

In NotePad++ you can use regular expressions to match characters.

[image]

Hey, you can even build a tiny PHP script to perform the replacement task for you!

Answer (score 0):

There are no unusual characters between the brackets—they must have been lost by the time they reached your post.

But 0b11000010,0b10100000 is 0xC2,0xA0, which is the UTF-8 encoding of U+00A0 Non Breaking Space. That's the character HTML's `&nbsp;` refers to. Some text editors will highlight it (and other non-ASCII spacing characters of various sorts).

Comment: I pasted that code to aptana, notepad, patpad++, sublime. none of the editor highlighted..

Answer (score 0):

When you have problems like this, it's often best to paste the code into a programmers editor. It will generally strip all formatting and "fancy stuff" and leave you with only plain ASCII.

I wish the COPY default was not "copy with all kinds of formatting and special codes and background colors and blinky lights"... but it is. ;)